# Checking out to another commit with git while reading the file

Tags: node.js, git, file-io

I am creating a server that handles version control of files in server and let the client view them at specific commit if they wanted.

The way I implement this is that when user clicks a specific commit, I call `checkout [hash of commit]` to revert the file back to what it was and then read from that file.

The problem is that two people may be trying to read different commits of the same repository at the same time, meaning the state of file may change while reading from the file.

I tried checking out another commit while reading from it and it seems to work okay but I cannot be sure when the it is scaled.

I am using `nodeJS` and `express` for my server. When nodeJS starts reading file, will it still be the same state as the point when it started reading or would it change along with the change that is forced by git if I checkout another commit while reading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using checkout, consider `show`:

```
git show <commit id>:<filename>
```

This will print the contents of the file at that commit. If you absolutely need it in a file, generate a unique temporary filename and redirect the output:

```
git show <commit id>:<filename> > tmpfile_uniquesuffix
```

Comment: hi, sorry I forgot to mention that I am working with an excel file. I cannot print on console

Comment: Then use my second example to redirect the output to a temporary file.

Comment: o wow damn... Works very well. I thought it would only transfer what is printed on the console. Thanks very much